# How to set chmod file permissions for a subdirectory of a vagrant shared folder?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, file-permissions, chmod, vagrantfile

How can I set vagrant to `chmod` a sub-directory of a *shared folder* to `777`?

The context is that I have a phpbb git repository in my `/vagrant` which is shared to `/var/www/phpbb` but I need to `chmod` `/var/www/phpbb/phpBB/cache` to `777` without `chmod`-ing all of `/var/www/phpbb`.

The line I have in my `VagrantFile` so far is:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "phpbb", "/var/www/phpbb", owner: "www-data", group: "vagrant"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "chmod 777 /var/www/phpbb/phpBB/cache"
end
```

See the docs for more details: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html